# Use promise to modify reactive data. The position of promise will cause the number of triggers to decrease

Tags: javascript, vue.js, asynchronous, promise, vuejs3

First Approach

```
    const list = reactive([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]); 
    const handleClick = () =>{
        list.push(...[11, 12, 13, 14, 15]);
        list.push(...[16, 17, 18, 19, 20]);
        Promise.resolve().then(() => {
            list.push(33)
        });
        
    };
```

Second Approach

```
    const list = reactive([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
    const handleClick = ()=>{
        Promise.resolve().then(() => {
            list.push(33)
        });
        list.push(...[11, 12, 13, 14, 15]);
        list.push(...[16, 17, 18, 19, 20]);
    };
```

the first function will trigger twice vue hooks `onUpdated`, but the second will trigger once, can anyone tell me why, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have known that vue will update data once in a sync code, because vue collect all the changes data to a microtask,and there is another microtask
(Promise.resolve()) in your code, In the first Approach, the vue-microtask is created befor the Promise.resolve(),so the Promise.resolve() will run after the vue upadted function,and then vue upadted again after Promise.resolve() running.

In the second  Approach,the vue-microtask is created after the Promise.resolve(), and when the vue-microtask running,the Promise has been resolved ,and the modify of list has been added to vue-microtask.

Answer (score 0):

It is because `Vue` uses an optimization mechanism based on `nextTick` to batch the updates.

In your first approach, you are pushing a bunch of values to the reactive array, Which would trigger the `onUpdate` hook once. Then the `Promise` resolves in a separate cycle, Which would trigger the `onUpdate` again.

But in the second approach, The `Promise` resolves before the `push` operations. Then the code pushes a couple more values to the array. The Vue's reactivity mechanism detects this and does these entire operations in a single tick. That triggers the `onUpdate` hook only once.

**More details:** [Why Vue will update only once when two reactive data mutation super close?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65035538/why-vue-will-update-only-once-when-two-reactive-data-mutation-super-close)